# Launch application from gmail app

Tags: android

I have a android application to preview .dst file type,i am able launch the app by clicking on file from the file explorer i did it by following code

```
           <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.DST" />
            <data android:host="*" />
           </intent-filter>
```

now i need to launch the app from the default gmail app,i think i need to change the 
 android:scheme="file"

tag ,please help me with the proper scheme for gmail application..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update the manifest as below

```
    <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.DST" />
        </intent-filter>
```